# How to search record in Datagridview using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, search, datagridview

I used this code to search record in Datagridview but when it's not worked. Please help me to finding the mistake!
[image: Snapshot1]

```
private void txtSearch_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text))
                {
                    dataGridView.DataSource = customerBindingSource;
                }
                else
                {
                    var query = from o in customerBindingSource.DataSource as List<Customer> 
                                where o.CustomerID == txtSearch.Text||o.Fullname.Contains(txtSearch.Text) || o.Email == txtSearch.Text || o.Address.Contains(txtSearch.Text) 
                                select o;
                    dataGridView.DataSource = query.ToList();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please give more details. What happens when you debug this code? Are you sure you want to reset the data source and not focus() on the cell that contains the matched contents? This is more typical search behavior. What you have coded sounds more like a filter

Comment: I don't think I need to reset the data source because everything work excluding search textbox. As you can see the picture, when I write in search textbox, nothing happen

Comment: try `where o.Customer.ID LIKE '%' + @id + '%' ` .... and `or` instead of `||`                               `connection.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtSearch.Text);`

Comment: I know you don't need to reset the data source.  That's what you were doing and I was pointing out that it was wrong.

Comment: @MichaelTedford What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to confirm, are you saying you type in the searchbox and press enter and nothing happens? Also , when you are comparing values, make sure you compare them by ignoring case:      key.Equals(txtSearch.Text,stringcomparison.ordinalignorecase)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've found the answers

Comment: No prob:)what was the issue?